# bash to grep file for match but include unique header rows

Tags: bash, grep

In the `bash` below I `loop` through a directory and run a `grep` on all the `.txt` files. What I am trying to do is include the header row of each file in the filtered result. Currently, the header is displayed in `stdout' and two new filtered files result with no headers.  The below seems close but I can't seem to include the unique headers in the output.Thank you :).

**bash**

```
for file in /home/cmccabe/compare/*.txt ; do
 bname=$(basename $file)
 pref=${bname%%.txt}
 [ "$file" = /home/cmccabe/compare/${pref}_filtered.txt ] && continue
 head -n 1 "$file"
 grep -wFf /home/cmccabe/compare/list $file > /home/cmccabe/compare/${pref}_filtered.txt
done
```

**file1**

```
Index   Chromosomal Position    Gene    
4   43394661    SLC2A1
22  166870221   SCN1A
22  166870952   CBS
```

**file2**

```
Chrom   Position    Gene Symbol Target ID
chr22   40742831    ADSL    AMPL3764590328
chr22   40745898    ADSL    AMPL5177720331
chr5    125885803   ALDH7A1 AMPL4306766150
chr5    178555085   FBN1    AMPL4306766155
```

**list** (used for the `grep`)

```
SLC2A1
SCN1A
ADSL
ALDH7A1
```

**desired file1_filtered output**

```
Index   Chromosomal Position    Gene
4   43394661    SLC2A1
22  166870221   SCN1A
```

**desired file2_filtered output**

```
Chrom   Position    Gene Symbol Target ID
chr22   40742831    ADSL    AMPL3764590328
chr22   40745898    ADSL    AMPL5177720331
chr5    125885803   ALDH7A1 AMPL4306766150
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep and bash's process substitution:

```
grep -wf <(head -n 1 file1; cat list) file1
```

Output:

```
Index   Chromosomal Position    Gene    
4   43394661    SLC2A1
22  166870221   SCN1A
```

---

```
grep -wf <(head -n 1 file2; cat list) file2
```

Output:

```
Chrom   Position    Gene Symbol Target ID
chr22   40742831    ADSL    AMPL3764590328
chr22   40745898    ADSL    AMPL5177720331
chr5    125885803   ALDH7A1 AMPL4306766150
```

Comment: or without process substitution: `head -n 1 file1; grep -wf list file1`

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this wrong. Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and then just do this:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
NR==FNR { genes[$0]; next }
FNR==1 {
    close(out)
    out = FILENAME
    sub(/\.txt$/,"_filtered&",out)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( $i == "Gene" ) {
            g = i
        }
    }
}
(FNR==1) || ($g in genes) { print > out }
' /home/cmccabe/compare/*.txt
```

It'll be more robust, efficient, and portable than what you are currently doing.